# How can I update a value which is provided by react context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

This is how I access the value provided by react context

This is the Provider :

```
import React from 'react';
import Provider from './Provider';
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is the index js file :

```
import Provider from './Provider';
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is how I get the value from context provider

```
import { Context } from './Provider';

        <div className="App">
            <Context.Consumer>
                {(value) => {
                    return <div>{value.state.name}</div>;
                }}
            </Context.Consumer>
        </div>
```

And now I want to change or update the state.name into a new value . How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it only [through the provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider).

Typically you pass a setter function in provider's value.

```
<Context.Provider value={{ value, setValue}} />
```

Here is an example with Provider pattern (like in question example):

```
class Consumer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {({ value, set }) => {
          return (
            <>
              {value}
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  set(value + 1);
                }}
              >
                Count
              </button>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Context.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          value: this.state.value,
          set: value => this.setState({ value })
        }}
      >
        <Consumer />
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit awesome-cannon-15d6m]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide a method from the context that will update the state. This is often done by creating a custom "Provider" component.

For example:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();
const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ value, updateContext ] = useState();
    return <MyContext.Provider value={{ value, updateContext }}>
        {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
}
```

Then inside your component, you can use the `updateContext` method to update the state.

```js
const { value, updateContext } = useContext(MyContext);
// Update the context
updateContext(10);
```